# how do I use sequelize findorcreate defaults

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use the findorcreate method in sequelize and it correctly inserts a row in my mysql database, but the values I put in the defaults section are not getting inserted.

Here is my code

```
return userDb
  .findOrCreate({
    defaults: {
      first_name: 'john',
      last_name: 'doe',
      email: 'test@test.com'
    },
    where: {
      user_id:UserId
    }
  })
```

here is the insert statement that the debug outputs

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`,`user_id`,`deleted`,`created_on`) VALUES (DEFAULT,200,'0',NOW());
```

as you can see it does not even attempt to insert the 3 fields I have in the default section. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like your `Model` isn't properly defined - the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` fields aren't being applied which is why the default values aren't being applied. Can you update to include the `Sequelize.define()`?

Comment: you are absolutely correct. if you will put this as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields that you are seeing in the `INSERT` are all default columns that Sequelize creates for a `Model`/table, so likely the `User` Sequelize `Model` is not defined properly. Because the `Model` doesn't contain these columns, the fields you are specifying in `defaults` cannot be applied.

Make sure that you define `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` in the `Sequelize.define()` for your `User` `Model`.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize();
const User = sequelize.define(
  'user',
  {
    first_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    last_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
  }
);
```